# List of Error Codes and Descriptions for OpenDSObject

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, ldap

I have the following but would like to have a full list of codes and their detailed descriptions if at all possible.

For example does the username exist? Is the password wrong?

```vb
Set oADsObject = oADsNamespace.OpenDSObject(strADsPath, strUserName,strPassword, 0)
Select Case Err.number
Case 0
  ' Success
    Session("Auth") = "YES"
Case -80070775
  'Locked
    errorMSG = "Account has been locked"
Case -2147943726, -2147023570, -2147024810, -2147023677, -2147022694
  ' Invalid
    Session("Auth") = "NO"
    errorMSG="Invalid details"
Case -2147023565
  ' Disabled
    Session("Auth") = "NO"
    errorMSG = "Disabled account"
Case -2147022987
  'Loceked
    Session("Auth") = "NO"
    errorMSG = "Locked Account"
Case -2147022989, -2147023541, -2147023688
  'Password expired
    Session("Auth") = "NO"
    errorMSG = "Password Expired"
Case else
  'Something else
    Session("Auth") = "NO"
    errorMSG = Err.Number
end select
```

Comment: Think you want these - [Win32 Error Codes for ADSI 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746530(v=vs.85).aspx) and [LDAP Error Codes for ADSI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746386(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: So there's no actual list - the 2nd links points to a lot of conversion between hex and binary

Comment: The second link is telling you how to convert a Win32 Error Code to an  LDAP error code.

Comment: The reason you can't find anything is because those errors are not LDAP they are being returned by NETLOGON. See [POINTER: "Quick Reference: Troubleshooting Netlogon Error Codes"](http://blogs.technet.com/b/brandonwilson/archive/2014/04/11/pointer-quot-quick-reference-troubleshooting-netlogon-error-codes-quot.aspx)

Comment: For the many lazy amongst us - I don't want to have to convert. Like the answer I gave below, a list or converted values is more useful

Comment: What you have to understand is LDAP is a way of querying various Directory Services not just AD and as such each Directory Services will have it's own set of error codes. LDAP also has it's own generic codes for thing's like not being able to connect to the Directory Services for example. Keep track of the errors and learn which codes relate to actions using a `Case Else` like you are doing. Would suggest storing a combination of `Err.Number`, `Err.Source` and Err.Description`. This explain's in more [LDAP Error Codes for ADSI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772197(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: This explains the whole process in terms of handling [ADSI Error Handling](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692841.aspx#EDAA).